# Bootstrap - Add checkbox below select in an inline form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a checkbox below a select element in an inline form. Is there an option to "break" the line in order to add the checkbox below?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I have at the moment:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pr3xtxf/14/)**

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control select-year text-smd">
          <option>Month</option>
          <option>January</option>
          <option>February</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control select-year text-smd">
          <option>Year</option>
          <option>2016</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group ml-15 mr-15">
      <label> - </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control select-year text-smd">
          <option>Month</option>
          <option>January</option>
          <option>February</option>
      </select>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control select-year text-smd">
          <option>Year</option>
          <option>2016</option>
      </select>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> I currently work here
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to put it in a `help-block` and right align it. Then add a little CSS to override the `form-group` aligment to the top.

```
.form-inline .form-group {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://bootply.com/dCbo7trghW

Answer (score 0):

best answer is that from Aramil (in the comments)
if you wan the "lazy" option, you can always use this
(i do not recommend this code, use the grid instead)

```
.checkbox-inline{
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  right: 11em;
}
```